# How do I find the data type of an AD attribute not having a value

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryentry

I am struggling to find the data type of AD attributes that are not having a value already.
Thus far a resulting DirecoryEntry only contains a property for attributes that already have a value. I can't find a method to obtain information about all other attributes.

Adding a value to the 'PropertiesToLoad' doesn't seem to do anything. The returned DirectoryEntry object contains all attributes (with values) regardless of what is added here.

Code used:

```
public void Test(string ldapPath)
{
   Type orgType;
   try
   {
     using (DirectoryEntry searchRoot = GetSearchRoot(ldapPath))
     {
        using (DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot))
        {
            search.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=coen))";

            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("msExchHomeServerName");

            SearchResult searchResult = search.FindOne();
            {
                using (DirectoryEntry entry = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry())
                {
                    if (entry != null)
                    {
                        if (entry.Properties.Contains("msExchHomeServerName"))
                        {
                            orgType = entry.Properties["msExchHomeServerName"].GetType();
                        }
                        else // The value is empty and NOT present in the current 'entry.Properties' object.
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Unknown type");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
     <handle exception>
   }
}
```

Is there a way to find the data type of the 'msExchHomeServerName' (or any of the 'empty' attributes) attribute?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Coen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Damien_The_Unbeliever who pointed me in the right direction, I managed to create the following method:

```
public Dictionary<string, ActiveDirectorySyntax> GetAttributeSyntaxes(List<string> lstAttributeNames)
{
    Dictionary<string, ActiveDirectorySyntax> dictRes = new Dictionary<string, ActiveDirectorySyntax>();

    if (lstAttributeNames.Count > 0)
    {
        DirectoryContext directoryContext = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.DirectoryServer,
                                                             m_Server, m_UserName, m_Password);

        using (ActiveDirectorySchema currentSchema = ActiveDirectorySchema.GetSchema(directoryContext))
        {
            using (ActiveDirectorySchemaClass objClass = currentSchema.FindClass("user"))
            {
                if (objClass != null)
                {
                    ReadOnlyActiveDirectorySchemaPropertyCollection propcol = objClass.GetAllProperties();

                    foreach (ActiveDirectorySchemaProperty schemaProperty in propcol)
                    {
                        foreach (string attrName in lstAttributeNames)
                        {
                            if (schemaProperty.Name.Equals(attrName))
                            {                                    
                                dictRes.Add(attrName, schemaProperty.Syntax);

                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return dictRes;
}
```

The returned 'schemaProperty.Syntax' contains sufficient information to determine the actual data type.

Thanks Damien!

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory has a schema. Obvious to say, not obvious to think about since, by default, you cannot explore it.

However, you can [Register the Active Directory Schema MMC Snap-In](https://www.briandesmond.com/active-directory/how-to-register-active-directory-schema-mmc-snap-in/)<sup>1</sup> and then, in a fresh instance of `MMC`, add that Snap-In.

This then allows you to explore the Classes and Attributes that make up your current AD schema (and add new classes/attributes if you know what you're doing and choose to do so).

`msExchHomeServerName` can then be discovered to be a "Unicode String", which means a plain `string` from C# should be acceptable. Note also that some types (particularly numeric ones) may also specify Minimums and Maximums which should be observed.

You can also explore the schema programatically via the [`ActiveDirectorySchema` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.activedirectoryschema?view=netframework-4.7.2), by e.g. calling `ActiveDirectorySchema.GetCurrentSchema();` and then explore from there.

---

<sup>1</sup>I cannot remember if you need to have installed the general Domain Admin tools (such as Users and Computers) in order for that DLL to exist on your system.

Comment: I think that blog owner has already clarified thar RSAT tool is required on non-DC systems!